# Partition induced by the Equivalence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I'm not sure I understand this concept.

Let's say we have a "Is parallel to" relation from the set of all lines in the Cartesian plane. What would be the partition induced by this relation?

Thank you.

Comment: Partition induced with respect to a line l will be: two sets. One having all lines parallel to l and the other having all lines which are not parallel to l.

Comment: For each line, define it's equivalence class to be the set of all lines parallel to it. This gives you the required partition.

Comment: The equivalence classes are composed of the lines that are parallel to each other. Remember you are partitioning the set of lines in the plane, not the plane itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two lines in the plane are parallel to each other iff they have the same slope. So a partition representative can be given as a Real number which is the slope of the collection of parallel lines with the same slope.

EDIT: as Will Jagy wrote, you also need to consider the lines with infinite slope, you can choose , say, a representative $x=k$ , where $k$ is constant.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: Agree with Ihechukwu :D

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely clear what you want, but a nice set of representatives is pairs of antipodal points on the standard unit circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1.$ For any family of parallel lines, there is one line that passes through the origin; it also passes through two points on the unit circle that are opposite ends of a diameter.

It does not suffice to use the concept of slope, vertical lines have infinite or undefined slope.

Comment: You're right; I edited a correction.

Answer (score 0):

The partition related to the relation $\sim$ on a set $S$ is given by the set of subsets of $S$ of the form $S_x = \{y \in S \mid x \sim y\}.$

Here, $S$ is the set of all lines in the plane, and the subsets forming the partition have the form $S_l = \{l' \in S \mid \text{l is parallel to l'} \}.$ Each such subset is in a one-to-one correspondence with the slope of any and each of the lines belonging to it. In other words, you have a bijection $(S/\sim) \cong \mathbb{\hat{R}} = \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\},$ under which $S_l$ corresponds to the slope of $l.$

Comment: More precisely, $(S/\sim) \cong \left(\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}\right)$, to account for the equivalence class of vertical lines.

Comment: @SteveKass Right!